# Using AngularJS directives to create a single corrent answer survey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I've created a single answer survey, and I want to translate it into a directive. I'ts a single answer because only one answer can be chosen at the same time, and it triggers x or y function (also ng-class) depending on the chosen answer.

I have the working functionality without directive in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvUHP/). As you'll see, every link triggers an different ng-click.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <a class="btn col-md-12" ng-click="continent='1'" ng-class="{'active' : continent == '1'}">North America</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <a class="btn col-md-12" ng-click="continent='2'" ng-class="{'active' : continent == '2'}">South America</a>
</div>
```

My problem is that this method doesn't work (or better, I don't know how to do it) when translated into a directive. You can see the [jsfiddle with the directive here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDTzN/3/).

And the js:

```
.directive('myContinent', function() {

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="col-md-4"> \
                <a class="btn col-md-12" ng-click="continent=\'1\'" ng-class="{active : continent == \'1\'}">{{text}} \
        </a> \
              </div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the easiest and clean ways is to pass the controller's scope variable to your directive scope (using `=`). You can save the selected continent in this variable and use it in multiple directive instances.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/xRy7H/1/

Comment: As Mr_Mig pointed out, using $parent is not really good practice. I edited the answer to pass the target scope variable explicitly. Use this one, it's much cleaner and just as easy :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all your `my-continent` directives has **different isolated scopes**, so **each of them** has `scope.continent == 1` after you click it.

You can modify your directive in any of the available solutions:

1. Build in on top of `radio` input group and standard angular form.
2. Use `$parent.continent` and assign different values to it (bad practice actually).
3. Use a single directive with **transclusion** (where options are transcluded into the 'parent' directive).

I'll leave the choice for you, as it depends on the overall architecture of your decision.